# Can I import my fonts through application.css instead of application.js in rails 6 with webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm thinking javascript doesn't use fonts, css does, so it should be imported through application.css but I'm not sure how

Answer (score 1):

yes using CSS font import style.

`<style> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@900&display=swap'); </style>`

Comment: Thanks And then webpacker knows about it or it doesn't make a difference whether or not webpacker knows about it?

Comment: get's compiled and work in production and development automatically